# ajaxForm with jquery validate

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am trying to combine ajaxSubmit with the validate plugin

Here is my code

It says the ajaxSubmit is not a function

```
$("#send-reply").validate({
        meta: "validate",
        errorElement: "em",
                errorClass: "error",
        validClass: "success",
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {

            $(element).closest("div.required").removeClass(validClass);
            $(element).closest("div.required").addClass(errorClass);
            $(element).addClass(errorClass);
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest("div.required").removeClass(errorClass);
            $(element).closest("div.required").addClass(validClass);
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
        },
        debug:true,
                rules: {
            message:{required:true}
        },
        messages: {
        message:'',

        },
               submitHandler: function(form) {

                 form.ajaxForm({ target:'#result',
           success: function() {
          $('#send-reply').fadeOut(500);
          $('#send-reply').remove();
        },clearForm: true});

}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit(....);
```

Two things there: 1) I think the function name is ajaxSubmit, where ajaxForm overrides the submit handler.  2) you might be passed the DOM form object instead of the jQuery object with the form

Comment: Odd that that it works 

The documentations says not to do $(form) because of recursion, guess that only applies to the normal .submit()

Comment: `form.submit()` would call the DOM `submit` method on a DOM object, whereas `$(form).submit()` would trigger submit events on the form using jQuery, calling your validation again -- therefore the recursion warning.